# Number of asymmetric relation

Tags: combinatorics, relations

Let $A$ be a set of $n$ elements. How can we calculate number of asymmetric relations on $A$? I googled for it and got the answer that the number is given by $3^{(n^2-n)/2}$, But I don't know how to derive it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given elements $a,b\in A$, either *blank*, *blank*, *blank*, or *blank*. If the relation $R$  on $A$ is asymmetric, only *blank*, …, or *blank* can occur. There are *blank* distinct unordered pairs of elements of $A$, so the total number of asymmetric relations on $A$ is *blank*.

Comment: What are these 'blank' ?

Comment: @alienCoder, they're blanks for you to fill in!

Comment: @alienCoder, did you figure it out? If not, where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes, I have figured it out. We can represent the pairs in matrix. Now for asymmetric we have three choices - either take a pair from upper triangle or take it from lower traingle or don't take it. So total 3^((n^2-n)/2). :)

Comment: @alienCoder, yes, I think you got it. If you found my answer helpful, you can accept it by clicking on the check mark.

Answer (score 4):

Let us take an example.

$$A = \{1,2,3\}$$
$$A\times A = \{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)\}$$

We know that, $(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)$ won't come in the asymmetric relation.(3 elements)

Remaining elements of $A\times B$ can be formed a group.

$[(1,2),(2,1)]$, $[(1,3),(3,1)]$, $[(2,3),(3,2)]$ (3 groups)

From every group, we can choose elements in 3 different ways.

1. choose 1st element.
2. choose 2nd element.
3. choose no elements.

That is, we can choose elements in $3^3$ different ways in this case.

Generalizing,

If there are $n$ elements in the set, the number of elements in the group is $\frac{\text{Total  number  of relations - reflexive  elements }}{2}=\frac{n^2 - n}{2}$

Each of these elements can be chosen in 3 ways. Therefore the number  of asymmetric  relations is $3^{\frac{n^2 - n}{2}}$

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Well explained!